# function that creates a PDF from a div and adds 4 dots with a cross to the 4 corners of each A4 page in the PDF in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a javascript function that creates a PDF from a div and adds 4 dots with a cross to the 4 corners of each A4 page in the PDF because I have to send the PDF to a printer because it's needed for a die-cutting machine. The point is that I think it runs the entire script but it doesn't start downloading the pdf, can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong??? thanks a lot to everyone.

This is code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-qZvrmS2ekKPF2mSznTQsxqPgnpkI4DNTlrdUmTzrDgektczlKNRRhy5X5AAOnx5S09ydFYWWNSfcEqDTTHgtNA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btn-one').click(function(e) {
            console.log('ok');
            // Creazione di un nuovo documento jsPDF
            var doc = window.jsPDF;

            // Funzione per aggiungere i pallini neri con croci ai quattro angoli di ogni foglio A4
            function addCorners() {
                var pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();

                for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
                    doc.setPage(i);

                    // Aggiungi pallini neri con croci agli angoli
                    doc.setDrawColor(0);
                    doc.setFillColor(0);
                    doc.circle(10, 10, 2, 'F');
                    doc.line(8, 10, 12, 10);
                    doc.line(10, 8, 10, 12);

                    doc.circle(10, 287, 2, 'F');
                    doc.line(8, 287, 12, 287);
                    doc.line(10, 285, 10, 289);

                    doc.circle(200, 10, 2, 'F');
                    doc.line(198, 10, 202, 10);
                    doc.line(200, 8, 200, 12);

                    doc.circle(200, 287, 2, 'F');
                    doc.line(198, 287, 202, 287);
                    doc.line(200, 285, 200, 289);
                }
            };

            // Funzione per creare il PDF da un div

            var element = document.getElementById('tutto'); // Sostituire 'divId' con l'ID del div da convertire

            // Opzioni per la creazione del PDF
            var options = {
                margin: 1,
                filename: 'output.pdf',
                image: {
                    type: 'jpeg',
                    quality: 0.98
                },
                html2canvas: {
                    scale: 2
                },
                jsPDF: {
                    unit: 'in',
                    format: 'a4',
                    orientation: 'portrait'
                }
            };

            // Creazione del PDF da un div utilizzando html2pdf
            html2pdf().from(element).set(options).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function(pdf) {
                addCorners(); // Aggiungi i pallini neri con croci agli angoli
                pdf.save();
            });

            var form = $(this).closest("form");

            var name = $(this).data("name");

            e.preventDefault();

            Swal.fire({
                title: `Download PDF avvenuto con successo`,
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: false,
                confirmButtonColor: 'rgba(244, 116, 78, 1)',
                confirmButtonText: 'Torna in Home',
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    form.submit();
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
```